# Incorrect encoding in urls causes Postgres error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my blog I use urls in the form /posts/

If another website links to one of my blog post with an incorrect URL containing invalid UTF-8 characters I get exceptions like the following one:

```
Blog::PostsController# (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) "PG::Error: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0xb0\n: SELECT \"posts\".* FROM \"posts\" WHERE (slug like 'Examp\xB0le-blog-post') LIMIT 1"
```

What's the best practice to cope with this kind of problems?
Should I check the encoding before queries the database? Should I catch those kind of exceptions?

Comment: Just making sure, you are **not** querying PGsql like this: `Post.where("slug like '#{params[:search]}'")` ? If yes, use `Post.where("slug like '?'", params[:search])` instead.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, but yeah I'm using the non dangerous/stupid way :)

Comment: Have you tried to put `# encoding: UTF-8` at the very top of the PostsController? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322433/encoding-and-utf-8-exceptions-after-upgrade-to-ruby-1-9-3-and-rails-3-2/16324815#16324815

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding before querying the database.  The best practice is to make sure you are not running queries that produces an error.

Not check the input before querying not only may raise errors but is a security vulnerability.

Concerning UTF-8 characters; Along with adding `# encoding: UTF-8` to the `.rb` file (this is an issue with is supposed to be fixed as of Ruby 2.0.0).  As pointed out by **MrYoshiji**.

Concerning database security:

> Instead of passing a string to the conditions option, you can pass an array to sanitize tainted strings like this:
>
> `Model.where("login = ? AND password = ?", entered_user_name, entered_password).first`
>
> As you can see, the first part of the array is an SQL fragment with question marks. The sanitized versions of the variables in the second part of the array replace the question marks. Or you can pass a hash for the same result:
>
> `Model.where(:login => entered_user_name, :password => entered_pas`
>
> The array or hash form is only available in model instances. You can try `sanitize_sql()`elsewhere. Make it a habit to think about the security consequences when using an external string in SQL.

[See here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#injection) for original documentation.

Comment: If you could please provide a more specific answer, e.g. what to check in this specific case to figure out if the encoding is correct I will pick your answer.

Comment: I should I check against string with invalid encoding? What's the method to check it they are utf-8?