# encoding and utf-8 exceptions after upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ever since I uploaded my new version to production from time to time I get encoding and 
utf-8 exceptions like these:

> Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (Windows-31J regexp with UTF-8 string)
>
> ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

after seeing some post i added ot my application.rb

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

What is it? and how do I fix? 
thanks

Comment: I had the same problem occuring "sometimes", I use now at the top of each `.rb` files the following: `#encoding: UTF-8`. Maybe this can help

Comment: OK thanks ill add it and update. then write your comment as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem occuring "sometimes", I use now at the very top of each `.rb` files the following:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

The problem occurs when the file contains one/several accent(s) (as a french guy, I sometimes use it in comments).